# Deploy Sequelize Nodejs API to Vercel

Tags: deployment, sequelize.js, vercel, nodejs-server

When I run locally everything works fine, but when I run on vercel:

```
const db = require('../../models')
```

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')","reason":{"errorType":"TypeError"}"

Even though I tested on Vercel, the database connection was successful

[image: image src code]

[image: image src code]

[image: image src code]

[image: image src code]

Please help me fix it.